# Is Sāṅkhya philosophy compatible with Advaita Vedānta?

Tags: philosophy, vedanta, advaita, sankhya

I think Advaita Vedānta holds that all of us are the same Self. (Advaita= Non-Dual)

But I think Sāṅkhya philosphy holds that all of us have different Self . (Correct me if I am wrong)

Are both of them compatible with each other?

Comment: That's kinda right. Sāṅkhya does assert the plurality of Self. This is in contradiction with the Advaitic view though. Śāṅkhya recognizes a multiplicity of distinct puruṣas, i.e. one for each self, while Vedāntic thought tends to view the ātman as ultimately singular.

Comment: not compatible with each other.